# ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript in footer

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can we call:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "KyAUIDFCS", "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>slidershow();</script>");
```

in user control, how can we implement this let me know because there page object in usercontrol. Are there any alternate ways.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? now you are just adding javascript to the page from code behind. When do you want this javascript to be executed? on page load? or?

Comment: there usercontrol used in footer, I want this javascritpt executed on button click (server side) This javascript neeed to executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f the javascript doesn't necessarly need to be executed after your server side code you can call this javascript function from within the OnClientClick property in your button.

Else you can just simple add the code you show above in your button click handler like:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
    // your code

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(UserControl1), "KyAUIDFCS", "slidershow();", true);
}
```

RegisterStartUpScript takes a parameter for AddscriptTags so you can get rid of the  tags and simply add a true parameter

or try

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
```

Instead of typeOf(Page) you can use any type of class. Since your usercontrol is a class itself you can just pass in the name of your usercontrol instead of Page

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScrip not working user control can you look into this..

Comment: You could also try: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript